# combine multi tables to one table in MS access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have 7 tables of information, all tables have the same fields.  I would like to combine the tables into 1 master table and then make a report and show this master table on the report.

Any and all assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the sql query for that?

```
CREATE Master_Table as (
SELECT * FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table2
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM Table3
...........)
```

That is if all the tables has the exact same fields(number and type)

Comment: thanks sagi, but unfortunately, I am new to SQL for access, where should I use this code, and will that make a master table ?